# Geckodriver Not working on Windows 7 even though provided in PATH

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

I have started using Robot Automation Framework

1) I have created a robot script

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation           This is a simple test with Robot Framework
Library                 Selenium2Library


*** Variables ***
${SERVER}               http://google.com
${BROWSER}              Firefox
${DELAY}                0


*** Keywords ***
Open Browser To Login Page
    Open Browser        ${SERVER}   ${BROWSER}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Selenium Speed  ${DELAY}
*** Test Cases ***
Valid Login
    Open Browser To Login Page
    [Teardown]    Close Browser
```

Now when I execute following command in the Terminal:

`pybot -d results smoketest.robot`

I get the error:

```
Valid Login                                                           Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.
webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x02BF6190>> ignored
Valid Login                                                           | FAIL |
WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

I have downloaded geckodriver version 11 and renamed it to wires.exe and added it to my environment variables please see my environment variables below :

```
C:\Users\diwakar>echo %PATH%
c:;C:\IEDriverServer.exe;C:\wires.exe;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Pyt
hon27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wb
em;C:\Users\diwakar\AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts;c:
```

I rebooted the system

Relaunched pycharm and re-execute the script still the same error. This is wasting a lot of my efforts now

```
I am using following versions :

decorator (4.0.10)
pip (9.0.1)
robotframework (3.0.1)
robotframework-selenium2library (1.8.0)
selenium (3.0.2)
setuptools (28.8.0)
Mozilla 50.1.0
```

Comment: I thought the GeckoDriver was meant to be in scripts? `C:\Python27\Scripts` is where mine lives ? I don't even edit the PATH. Never have come to think of it...

Comment: I also don't think you can change the name of the executable... Not sure on that one, but maybe...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't rename the driver, and you can't put the driver itself in PATH. PATH needs to contain the *folder* that contains geckodriver with its original name.

Comment: sorry brian, it doesn't works .wonder the same thing works without any gecko driver with  selenium version == 2.53.6 and mozilla firefox 46.0  but once both updated , things stop working. I did what you said and added file with executable path but still it doesn't works

Comment: Bryan , if you can explain it with an example , i will be grateful to you

Comment: As already stated by @Bryan that RobotFramework expects the file to be named geckodriver.exe and that is should be accessible. This accessibility is achieved by putting the file in a folder that is already in the PATH, or adding the new folder path to PATH.

On my own PC I have a folder c:\Selenium\Webdrivers\ in which my web driver executables reside. This folder I added to the windows PATH. So when I want to add a new driver, I just add it to this folder and the rest is already taken care of.

Comment: thanks guys , this was so simple , i am embarresed i wastedmy whole day in such a simple problem . But nothing like getting a good buddies here who can correct even your most silly mistakes thanks @Bryan Oakley and , A.Kootstra